# Thymeleaf composite components

Tags: java, spring, composite-component, thymeleaf

Is there any way of making composite components (like in JSF) using Thymeleaf? I found out how to send parameters to fragments that can be retrieved using the expression language. But I haven't figured out how to send **markup** to fragments like you can in JSF.

For example, I have several pages that have very similar menus on the left. I would like to be able to use a single fragment on all my pages, but passing some markup to be displayed at the bottom of the menu. Some pages have to display text at the bottom, some have to display text, for example, it's actually more complicated than that.

```
<div class="menu" th:frament="menu">
    <a th:text="${menuItem1}"></a>
    <a th:text="${menuItem2}"></a>
    <a th:text="${menuItem3}"></a>
    <markup sent as parameter /> <!-- how do I do this? -->
</div>



<div th:substitueBy="template :: menu" th:with="menuItem1=item1, menuItem2:item2, menuItem3:item3">
    <markup to be sent as parameter /> <!-- this does not work -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to create composite components with exchangeable content. That's why I developed the [thymeleaf-component-dialect](https://github.com/Serbroda/thymeleaf-component-dialect).

With this dialect, you can write components like this:

**Create a component (a thymeleaf fragment) with a `<tc:content/>` tag**

```
<div th:frament="menu">
    <a th:text="${menuItem1}"></a>
    <a th:text="${menuItem2}"></a>
    <a th:text="${menuItem3}"></a>
    <tc:content></tc:content>
</div>
```

**Use the component**

```
<tc:menu>
    <h1>Some Header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</tc:menu>
```

**The result will be**

```
<div>
    <a>Menu Item 1 Text</a>
    <a>Menu Item 2 Text</a>
    <a>Menu Item 3 Text</a>
    <h1>Some Header</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
```

The dialect is new and is still in alpha state. Feedback is welcome.

Comment: A few years late, but thanks! Unfortunately I don't use thymeleaf anymore so I can't test out your library

Comment: Yes, it's late. But for people who are also looking for this question, the answer might be helpful.

Comment: Isn't it possible to pass parameter (i.e. url/label for menu items)?

Comment: wat are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

But you will have to write all menu container attributes to every page you use it.

I dont really like this way, but I think it should works :p

**Template:**

```
<div th:frament="menu">
    <a th:text="${menuItem1}"></a>
    <a th:text="${menuItem2}"></a>
    <a th:text="${menuItem3}"></a>
</div>
```

**Page:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <div th:include="template :: menu" 
         th:remove="tag" 
         th:with="menuItem1=item1, menuItem2:item2, menuItem3:item3" />
    <more markup/>
</div>
```