# How do I send a variable to external scope in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a template with the next structure:

```
 <html>
 <body>
       <th:block th:replace="${thymeleafContent}"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I use more components to generate thymeleafContent, but now I need the text from one of those components to be used outside the thymeleafContent to be something like this:

```
 <html>
 <body>
       <th:block th:utext="${textUsedInAComponent}"/>
       <th:block th:replace="${thymeleafContent}"/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Could this be done in a clean way?

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200971/thymeleaf-composite-components?rq=1?

Comment: I'm not familiar with thymeleaf, but can't you just do ${thymeleafContext.someVariable} ? (Assuming that is an object, not just a string)

Comment: @Magic-Mouse, I need to do almost revert of that stuff

Comment: they are treated as Strings, or I can change them to have another component inside thymeleafContent and to same the text as a variable of that component, but thymeleafContent will be a String not an Object